# Find the minimum number of needed transformations given input and target string

Tags: c, string, algorithm

Given that I have an **input** string, for example:  `aab` 
And I am given a **target** string, for example: `bababa` 
And then I am given a set of transformation rules. For example:

```
ab -> bba
b -> ba
```

How could I do, in C, an algorithm that would find the **minimum** number of transformations that would need to be applied in the input string to get the target string.

In this example, for example, the number would be 3.  Because we would do:

```
1 - Apply rule 1 (abba)
2 - Apply rule 1 again (bbaba)
3 - Apply rule 2 (bababa)
```

It could happen that given an input and a target, there is no solution and that should be noticed too.

I am pretty much lost in strategies on doing this.  It comes to my mind creating an automata but I am not sure how would I apply in this situation.  I think is an interesting problem and I have been researching online, but all I can find is transformations given rules, but not how to ensure it's a minimum.

EDIT: As one of the answers suggested, we could do a graph starting from the initial string and create nodes that are the result of applying transformations to the previous node.  However, this brings some problems, from my point of view:

1. Imagine that I have a transformation that looks like this a --> ab.  And my initial string is 'a'. And my output string is 'c'.  So, I keep doing transformations (growing the graph) like this:

   a -> ab
   ab -> abb
   abb -> abbb
   ...

How would I know when I need to stop building the graph?

1. Say I have the following string aaaa, and I have a transformation rule like aa->b.  How would I create the new nodes? I mean, how would I find the substrings in that input string and remember them?

Comment: I'd start by designing the algorithm *outside* of C (or any language), then code it *with* C.

Comment: WhozCraig I agree. The problem is the algorithm itself. I don't know how to start with it.

Comment: If you haven't already, you should check out [Formal Grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) and [Parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).  I know it's a huge topic, but if you can figure out the type/complexity of the grammar you're dealing with, you can easily find the algorithms that can parse it (or that it's [Context-Sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar), and thus nightmarishly difficult).

Comment: is yous grammar has only two elements such as a & b?

Comment: No amin k. It can have more elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think there is an efficient solution for this. I think you have to do breadth-first search. by doing that you will know that as soon as you *have* a solution that it is *a shortest* solution.

**EDIT**:

Image: modify string breadth first

[image: search string breadth first]

Every layer is made from the previous by applying all possible rules to all possible substrings. For example the `b->ba` rule can be applied to `abba` for each `b`. It is important to only apply a single rule and then remember that string (eg ababa and abbaa) in a list. You have to completely have each layer in a List in your program before you start the next Layer (=breadth first).

**EDIT 2**:

You write you now have an output `c`. For this you obviously need a rule with `XX->c`. So say you have rule `aaa->c`. Now in layer 2 you will have a string `aaa` which came from some `a->aa` rules. You will then apply `a->aa` again and get `aaaa`, that is ok, since you should go breadth first you will THEN apply the `aaa->c` rule to `aaa` and now have layer 3 consisting of `aaaa`, `c` and others. You do not continue modifying `aaaa` because that would go to layer 4, you already found the target `c` in layer 3 so you can stop.

**EDIT 3**:

You now ask if you can decide for an unspecified set of rules how you can decide when to stop layering. In general it is impossible, it is called the Halting problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem .

**BUT** For specific rules you can tell if you can ever reach the output.

- Example 1: if the target contains an atom that no rule can provide (your 'c'-Example).
- Example 2: if your rules are all either increasing the string's length or keeping the length as it is (no rules that *decrease* the length of the string)
- Example 3: you can drop certain rules if you found by algorithm that they are cyclic
- Other examples exist

Comment: Imagine a graph. A string (original, target and intermediates) is a node in that graph, a transformation is a directed edge in that graph.

Comment: But how do I generate the intermediate nodes in the graph? I mean, what would be the algorithm to keep generating intermediate strings, and when do I stop? Imagine that there is no solution, when would I stop?

Comment: I will draw a quick picture. One moment.

Comment: Thanks a lot eznme. Once I have a base, I think I will be able to do something...

Comment: Sure. Expanded the answer.

Comment: eznme, I think I start to get what you are trying to say. However, some doubt rises here.  I will edit my question.

Comment: eznme, the tricky part here is that I would need to find if there are no transformations that would bring me from INPUT to OUTPUT. So, imagine that I don't have the 'c'.  It can happen that by doing transformations I don't get to the output.  I would like to know when to stop building the graph if I haven't found a solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25009/discussion-between-hommer-smith-and-eznme)

Comment: eznme I have coded this, but I am having troubles in seeing how can I build each layer before going to the next one. I have opened a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048037/make-a-tree-grow-horizontally-applying-modifications-to-current-node -- Maybe you can see how can I solve this