# Make a tree grow horizontally applying modifications to current node

Tags: c, recursion, tree

Given an input, I am trying to build a tree which should grow horizontally applying transformations to that input and the consequent children.

For example, given the input 'aab' and two transformation rules like:

```
ab -> bba
b -> ba
```

A tree like this would need to be built:

[image]

I have written the code, but the way I have done it, my tree works vertically, and I don't want that. I need it to work horizontally and I fail to see where/how I would write the recursion.  Here is what I have right now:

```
   #include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct t_string_node {
    struct t_string_node *next;
    char *value;
} string_node;

typedef struct t_transformation_rule {
    struct t_transformation_rule *next;
    char *needle;
    char *replacement;
} transformation_rule;


void findTransformations(char *origin, string_node **transformations, char *needle, char *replacement)
{
    char *str = origin; 

    for (char *p = str; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        if (strncmp(p, needle, strlen(needle)) == 0) {
            char *str_ = malloc(strlen(str)+1+strlen(replacement)-strlen(needle));
            strcpy(str_, str);
            char *p_ = p - str + str_;
            memmove(p_+strlen(replacement), p_+strlen(needle), strlen(p_)+1-strlen(replacement));
            memcpy(p_, replacement, strlen(replacement));
            //Create new string node.
            string_node *transformation; 
            transformation = malloc(sizeof(string_node));
            transformation->value = str_;
            transformation->next = NULL;

            while (*transformations != NULL) {
                transformations = &(*transformations)->next;
            }
            *transformations = transformation;
        }
    }
}

int hasTransformation(char *origin, char *target, transformation_rule *list_of_rules)
{
    int level;
    level = 0;
    int found;

    string_node *current;
    current = malloc(sizeof(string_node));
    current->value = origin;
    current->next = NULL;

    if(list_of_rules == NULL) {
        if (strcmp(origin, target) == 0) {
            printf("Solution in 0 steps");
            return 1;
        } else {
            printf("No solution");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    string_node *transformations;
    transformations = NULL;

    while (current != NULL) {
      findTransformations(current->value, target, &transformations, list_of_rules->needle, list_of_rules->replacement);
      findTransformations(current->value, &transformations, list_of_rules->next->needle, list_of_rules->next->replacement);
      current = current->next;
    }

    while (transformations != NULL) {
        printf("%s \n", transformations->value);
        transformations = transformations->next;
    }

    return 1;
}

void main()
{
  char *input = "aab";
  char *target = "bababab";
  char *needle = "ab";
  char *replacement = "bba";

  transformation_rule *list_of_rules;
  list_of_rules = NULL;
  list_of_rules = malloc(sizeof(transformation_rule));

  list_of_rules->needle = "ab";
  list_of_rules->replacement = "bba";
  list_of_rules->next = NULL;

  //Create another rule
  transformation_rule *new_rule;
  new_rule = malloc(sizeof(transformation_rule));
  new_rule->needle = "b";
  new_rule->replacement = "ba";
  new_rule->next = NULL;
  list_of_rules->next = new_rule;

  int has_trans;

  has_trans = hasTransformation(input, target, list_of_rules);
}
```

Anybody could help me to realize how would I do this so that the tree grows horizontally instead of vertically?

Thanks

Comment: `char *str_ = malloc(strlen(str)+1+strlen(replacement)-strlen(needle));
            strcpy(str_, str);` will overrun the destination string if relacement happens to be smaller than needle. BTW: you can simplify this kind of logic by calling strlen() only once (before the loop) and by working with indexes instead of pointers. You can also simplify by replacing the while loops by for loops. BTW: diagnostic output should go to stderr (and contain a \n) And, finally: main() should return int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@All: This question is a continuation on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033832/find-the-minimum-number-of-needed-transformations-given-input-and-target-string/15033902#15033902) question (even using the picture i made).

Now the answer to the depth-first vs breadth-first issue: To to this you should not build a tree-datastructure at all. All you have to care about is the ***current*** layer and the ***next*** layer.

So you just create one list for each. In the beginning you put your start-string in the ***current*** and your ***next*** is empty. You then see that you can derive `abba` and `aaba` so you put them into next. Then you *clear* ***current*** and put everything from ***next*** into ***current*** and then clear ***next***.

You keep repeating this until you notice that you are adding your target string to ***next*** then you can stop searching.

*And*: As i said in the answer referenced above: This may not terminate and is indecidable whether it will eventually terminate (Halting-problem), BUT there are many heuristics to detect non-termination in *specific* cases.

**EDIT**: Ok, here's the code!

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
struct list_s {
    struct list_s* next;
    char* entry;
};
char* paste(char* begin, int len1, char* mid, int len2, char* end, int len3) {
    char* a = malloc(len1+len2+len3+1);
    memcpy(a, begin, len1);
    memcpy(a+len1, mid, len2);
    memcpy(a+len1+len2, end, len3);
    a[len1+len2+len3] = '\0';
    return a;
}
void push(struct list_s** top, char* p) {
    struct list_s* l = malloc(sizeof(struct list_s));
    l->next = *top;
    l->entry = p;
    *top = l;
}
char* pop(struct list_s** top) {
    char* res = (*top)->entry;
    struct list_s* next = (*top)->next;
    free(*top);
    *top = next;
    return res;
}
int main() {
    char* input = "aab";
    // char* target = "bbabaa"; // 11th try
    char* target = "abbaa";     // 5th try
    // char* target = "bababab";// has no solution
    #define cRules 2
    char* from[cRules] = {"ab", "b"}; // ab->bba and b->ba
    char* to[cRules] = {"bba", "ba"};
    struct list_s* current = 0;
    struct list_s* nextLayer = 0;
    char* inputAlloc = malloc(strlen(input));
    strcpy(inputAlloc, input);
    push(&current, inputAlloc);
    int counter = 0;
    while(current) { // = while not empty
        char* cur = pop(&current);
        int lenCur = strlen(cur);
        printf("%s:\n", cur);
        int iRule=0; for(; iRule<cRules; ++iRule) { // for each rule
            char* pos = cur;
            for(;;) { // apply the rule wherever it fits
                pos = strstr(pos, from[iRule]);
                if(!pos) break;
                char* mod = paste(
                    cur, pos-cur, 
                    to[iRule], strlen(to[iRule]), 
                    pos+strlen(from[iRule]), 
                    cur+lenCur-(pos+strlen(from[iRule])) );
                printf("->%s\n", mod);
                if(!strcmp(mod, target)) {
                    printf("DONE\n");
                    return 0;
                }
                push(&nextLayer, mod);
                ++pos;
            }
        }
        free(cur);
        if(!current) { // next round!
            current = nextLayer;
            nextLayer = 0;
        }
        ++counter;
        // here you can add some of the fail-conditions we talked about
        if(counter==100) {
            printf("heuristic: no solution\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @HommerSmith please tell me if any problem occurs or if i should write example-code.

Comment: eznme what do you mean "you keep repeating this"? Could you provide some C code? I mean, I am unsure on how would I do the logic beginning from the start-string. I fail to see how the logic would be from there (which kind of loops, funcions...). Thank you very much

Comment: I have edited my question with the code I have right now.  I am hardcoding an input, target and two transformation rules, but the point is that I get pretty much lost in how the logic should for the hasTransformation function.

Comment: @HommerSmith it took me much longer than i thought because there is so much book-keeping, but now it is finished.

Comment: @HommerSmith made a small correction: `pos+=strlen(from[iRule]);` is now `++pos;`.

Comment: eznme, thank you very much. I have to take a deep look, but it looks neat. But just one question: what for(;;) { // apply the rule wherever it fits means?

Comment: @HommerSmith for example if you have 'ababa' and a rule 'ba->a' then that rule can be applied in 2 places, so we have to add both 'aaba' and 'abaa' into the modified-list.

Comment: but what the empty for(;;) does? Isn't it missing something?

Comment: for(;;) just loops forever. until there is a `break` or `return`.

Comment: eznme have you tried the code by chance? I am getting a segmentation fault when executing it. I have tried with input = 'aab' and target = 'bababa' which should resolve in 3 steps, but I get a segmentation fault...

Comment: I have, and it doesn't segfault on my machine (win xp). Please tell me on which line it segfaults and i will fix it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25047/discussion-between-hommer-smith-and-eznme)